# Purpose of using "as he did" in between a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in my history books which was:

> He reached his destination three weeks later, making a fistful of salt **as he did** and thereby making himself a criminal in the eyes of the law.

Has the phrase "as he did" been used to lay emphasis or is it something else?

Comment: 'As he did so' would seem to make more sense, though I don't know in what historical context making salt was a criminal offence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross post of the [identical question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215241/purpose-of-using-as-he-did-in-between-a-sentence) asked at ELL just two hours beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, As KB says, it means "As he did so"; in other words, he made a fistful of salt as he reached his destination. No - it's not for emphasis.

*[The rest of this answer is to do with the historical context. The original question was not concerned with this, so stop reading any time you like!]*

Without any context it was difficult to say why making salt would be an offence. But it reminded me of the Bible story of the [Pharisees](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=DIV2&byte=4426641) watching Jesus and the disciples for any minor infraction.

In [**context**](http://ugcinhistory.blogspot.com/2011/12/gandhi-his-thought-and-philosophy.html) all becomes clear.

In 1930 **Mahatma Gandhi** led a march to break one of the most widely disliked laws in British India, which gave the state a monopoly in the manufacture and sale of salt. Salt was indispensable yet people were forbidden from making it even for domestic use, compelling them to buy it from shops at a high price. By making the state monopoly of salt his target, Gandhiji hoped to mobilise a wider discontent against British rule.